# Insert value from one dataframe to another based on search

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes like below :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
{
    'sentence': ['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text1', 'text1', 'text2'],
    'label': ['abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'ghi']
}
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
{
    'sentence': ['html_text1', 'html_text2', 'html_text3', 'html_text4'],
    'label': ['abc', 'abc', 'def', 'ghi']
}
)
```

I want to iterate over the 2 dataframes and create a new dataframe. The condition for creating new dataframe is :

When **label** of df2 matches with **label** of df1, that record of df2 should be inserted above matching record of df1. So the final dataframe should look like :

[image]

P.S: I have not been able to work out the logic yet so I am not able to put sample code. However, I am trying to use dataframe.iterrows() to work on the above case.

Answer (score 2):

`concat` and `sort_values` with a stable sort:

```
out = (pd.concat([df2, df1])
         .sort_values('label', kind='stable', ignore_index=True)
         [['label', 'sentence']]
      )
```

output:

```
  label    sentence
0   abc  html_text1
1   abc  html_text2
2   abc       text1
3   abc       text2
4   abc       text3
5   def  html_text3
6   def       text1
7   ghi  html_text4
8   ghi       text1
9   ghi       text2
```

Ensuring df2 contains labels from df1:

```
out = (pd.concat([df2[df2['label'].isin(df1['label'])], df1])
         .sort_values('label', kind='stable', ignore_index=True)
         [['label', 'sentence']]
      )
```

Comment: This doesn't work if df2 contains a label that is not in df1.

Comment: @tcotts this is not specified by OP, but easily handled, let me add an update

Comment: Thanks for the help @mozway. Can we have a solution even if df2 contains label not present in df1?? The final DF should contain all records from df2. Sorry, I forgot to put that in OP.

Comment: @Crusader check my answer carefully, I provided 2 alternatives. If neither works for you, please provide an example demonstrating that and the expected output.

Comment: Ohh yes, The 1st alternative works. Can you explain which part of code is keeping "html_text" on top? I did not quite understand it.

Comment: nvm, I got the code!!. Thanks!!

Comment: @Crusader the fact that we `concat` with `df2` first **and** use a stable sort ;)